# ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied on AWS eb init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I try to initialize an elastic beanstalk application with eb cli using command eb init. After several steps it asks for some input to create a public key. However, when I enter input it gives "ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: " error. My IAM user roles are listed here :

```
 AWSCodeCommitFullAccess
 AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess
 AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
 AmazonECS_FullAccess
 AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
 AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role
 AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole
 AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk
 AWSElasticBeanstalkReadOnly
```

Do I need an additional permission to be able to intialize a beanstalk application?

Comment: Do you know why you have both `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk` and `AWSElasticBeanstalkReadOnly`?  That seems contradictory.

Answer (score 6):

It fails to create an ssh public key for your instance during the `eb init`.
You need a [IAM policy that has `ec2:CreateKeyPair` permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateKeyPair.html).

Answer (score 6):

It's about permissions.

1. Go to AWS Dashboard
2. Search for IAM
3. Go to Users
4. Select the user (Or user group assigned to that user)
5. Make sure that the user has the following permissions:

- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk

Comment: So AWS has all these permissions to help security, completely skips over them in their "Getting Started" docs, and then developers just say "Grant all permissions" is the right answer? SMH, not saying your wrong, just bad system design on AWS's part... If its so complicated you just default to 'chmod 777', the security system wasn't well thought out...

Comment: @JohnRobinson Amen

Answer (score 2):

[EBS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.managed-policies.html) says that it should be sufficient enough to create EBS applications, but looks like it's not.

Only after I added the next permission to my user via the IAM service I was able to run `eb init`:

`AdministratorAccess`

If it does not help, consider adding the `--debug` flag to your command:

`eb init --debug`

You can see more context about why the operation fails.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but the more targeted approach from @DonRocks below also worked for me (ie. adding those three policies instead of `AdministratorAccess`), so I opted for that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add AmazonEC2FullAccess permission to the default iam user on your local machine.
access aws console

1. search iam.
2. select the iam user, which is your default user.
3. click on button with attach existing permission.
4. click on add permission and search for AmazonEC2FullAccess then add it

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and the trick was to **ensure that my IAM user had the following permissions:**

- AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier

... this was **in addition to AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk   and AmazonEC2FullAccess** - which didn't seem logical to me.

See *IAM > Users > [user_name] > Permissions > **attach policies directly***

Answer (score 0):

I had defined the indicated permissions of other answers here but it still wasn't working.

I had to change the "Permissions Limit" (right below the "Permissions Policy"), and then it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to me, previous answer can be a part of the solution.

My steps :

- try eb init <my_folder> -> ERROR: NotAuthorizedError
- eb start create folder .elasticbeanstalk + file config.yml
- Add a new roles from AWS
- DELETE .elasticbeanstalk + file config.yml existing
- Finaly try again eb init <my_folder>

Answer (score 0):

For me it didn't work at first with only `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk` permission.

But it did after I had added the`AmazonEC2FullAccess` permission suggested by [@Omar Magdy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73460077/21496389).

Since it failed right after it created the key pair I don't think you need to add another `ec2:CreateKeyPair` permission.

Note the message with `--debug`: suggested by [@Andrew Kicha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76281413/21496389)

> `Uploaded SSH public key for "aws-eb" into EC2 for region eu-central-1.`