# NotAuthorizedError while initializing AWS Elastic Beanstalk in Express back-end

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my Express + MySQL + React project on AWS EB for my client and was invited as an IAM user. I tried to initialize EB env using the command line below
`eb init --platform node.js`
I typed aws access key id and aws secret key and got the error below
`ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Access Denied`
I confirmed if I have enough permission.
Have no idea why this still happens.

I have written above.

Comment: It seems to be a permission issue only, can you share what all the permissions you have as iam user? Also please check this related [ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied on AWS eb init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259774/error-notauthorizederror-operation-denied-on-aws-eb-init?rq=2)

Comment: So you mean, I need to generate a key pair?

Comment: EB applications require many permissions, permission to create key pair is one of them. You need to make sure you have enough permission to create an EB application.